# Error occur when using Membership.GetUser()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

When I use `Membership.GetUser()` method  and include `using System.Web.Security;` namespace the error shows that

> "The type 'System.Web.Security.MembershipUser' is defined in an
>   assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'System.Web.ApplicationServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. C:\Raj\Orchard\src\Orchard.Web\Modules\test\Controllers\VideoController.cs"

Answer (score 2):

You need to do "Add Reference" on System.Web.ApplicationServices assembly in your Visual Studio project. Refer to the following link for more information: [How to: Add or Remove References in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> To add a reference in Visual C#
>
> In Solution Explorer, right-click the project node and click Add
>   Reference.
>
> In the Add Reference dialog box, select the tab indicating the type of
>   component you want to reference.
>
> Select the components you want to reference, and then click OK.

Answer (score 2):

Although `Memebership` class resides in System.Web assembly, the `GetUser` method returns object of type `MembershipUser` and this type is defined in `System.Web.ApplicationServices` assembly.

Therefore you need to add reference to that assembly so that you can use the said type in the code.